# Transforming String variable into JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to create a dynamic form.

For now I decided to add some options as a String variable (I know, horror code, but if you have any other sugestion, leave as a comment) that is "pasted" into the JSP.

I got the "pasting" part ok, but I can't use JSTL expressions, such as a forEach loop, which would make the code less horrific (say I want to make a multiple checkbox). In the above example I get only one option with a ${loopvariable} inside.

Take a peek (the string I'm passing as parameter):

```
String extraHtml = "<select name='HarmonicDecomposition' multiple><c:forEach begin='1' end='15' varStatus='loop'><option value='${loop.index}'>${loop.index}</option></c:forEach>"
```

In the JSP I have the following (ignore the way I named the variables):

```
<c:if test="${type.extraHtml != null}">
        <br/>
            ${type.extraHtml}
        <br/>
</c:if>
```

Can I make that forEach loop work? If not, why? What Options do I have?

Comment: What do you mean by `but I can't use JSTL expressions`? did you import the `JSTL` library in your JSP?

Comment: Nope, JSTL is imported. I think the problem is that JSTL is parsed and the tags are made into Java Code. Then, the variable is passed with tags inside the string. These tags do not run and are discarded.